# Spannables & Spanned Text in Android EditText

Tags: android

I fetch html data and wish to show it in a rich text editor in android. I can do it as long as long as they just have basic stuff like bold, italic. How can I findout if the text has other Spanned or spannables used which gives me early warning for incompatibility?

Spanned.getSpans() works but its specific for each span e.g. underline, fontFace. I would have to call getSpans for all variants. Isn't there a method that would return all types of spans used in the text?

I dont really wann use regex or string operations for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `Object.class` to `Spanned.getSpans()` to get all spans or you can pass `CharacterStyle.class` to get all style spans.

Comment: StyleSpan [] spanned = (StyleSpan[]) spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length(), Object.class); doesnt work, neither does class cast to Spanned[]

Comment: If you past `Object.class` as the last argument, then the result is `Object[]`, not `StyleSpan[]`.

Comment: The idea is that you pass some class and get all spans which are instances of this class or its subclass.

Comment: That means I`ll have to do what I feared most... checking it against for each one of the android.text package

Comment: No, that doesn't. If you want to check whether the `Spanned` contains ANY spans, then you can call `Spanned.getSpans()` with `Object.class` as the last parameter, don't cast the result to any other type and check if the result is empty or not.

Comment: But I wish to check if non bold, non Italic spans exist

Comment: If you want to check only `StyleSpan`s, then just use `spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length(), StyleSpan.class)`. If you want to check some (but not all) subclasses of `CharacterStyle`, then do `spannable.getSpans(0, spannable.length(), CharacterStyle.class)`, iterate through the returned array and perform `instanceof` checks. Or you can create `Set<Class> spanClassSet` and check `spanClassSet.contains(span.getClass())`.

Comment: There is some sort of flaw in android's Spans implementation. Even when a BulletSpan exists, it doesnt detect it.

Comment: That's strange, because current implementation stores all spans in an array and checks spans' types using `Class.isInstance()`. So it must work. Maybe you're trying to get it with wrong base type? Check the implementation: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/text/SpannableStringInternal.java;h=0412285bc3b02ad62f335bc4a83b735b13b2d916;hb=HEAD.

Comment: And if you're still experiencing some problems, try to debug your app with Android's source code: http://johnsenf.blogspot.com/2011/04/android-sources-in-eclipse.html.